# os.scandir throws mysterious NotADirectory error

Tags: python, filesystems, file-not-found

while I was writing a function loop through a folder

code here:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path


path = Path(r'D:\full')
for i in os.scandir(path):#folders
     for j in os.scandir(i.path):#subdict
          for k in os.scandir(j.path):#files
               print(k.path)
```

it seems to stop whilst a specific folder, a specific file
one that seems to be called 12.288.csv
the full error is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\project\MOTOR.py", line 7, in <module>
    for k in os.scandir(j.path):#files
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'D:\\full\\normal\\12.288.csv'
```

interestingly though, the directory does exist, what is wrong?

Alright, I already tried

```
\-double slashes
\-raw string
\-checking if directory exists
\-forward slashing and backward slashing
```

Comment: `D:\\full\\normal\\12.288.csv` is a FILE, not a DIRECTORY.  You can't call `scandir()` on a file.

Comment: Thanks that helped, wish I could up vote you